# Rotational motion - torque

Tags: torque

I recently read a book of introduction of the rotational motion, but I do not quite understand the way author analysed the problem.

Situation: A light rod rests on a pivot passing throughout its centre of mass A, force $F
_1$ acts vertically down on the rod to the right of the pivot point at a distance $x_1$ from the pivot. Force $F_2$ acts vertically downwards on the rod at a distance $x_2$ to the left of the pivot. What is the condition, in terms of the $F$'s and $x$'s, that the rod does not rotate about its pivot point?

The author analyses this problem with introducing a fictitious force $f$ at either end of the rod, acting along the length of the rod. Saying that whatever the magnitude of $f$, the force that results from adding together the $f$'s and $F$'s must pass throughout a point $P$ vertically above the pivot point $O$ or otherwise the rod will rotate. He further mentioned that the lines of action of combination of $f$ and $F_1$ and of the combination of $f$ and 
$F_2$ meet at a height $y$ above $O$. There are force vector diagram and position vector diagram as attached picture.[image]

At this point, I do not understand:

1) Why the fictitious force $f$ acting along the length of rod will cause rotation? 
2) Why the lines of action of combination of $f$ and $F_1$ and of the combination of $f$ and $F_2$ meet at a height $y$ above $O$. What does it mean and why?
3) Why there is resultant force between $f$ and $F_2$ in the diagram and so for $f$ and $F_1$?

I am sorry to ask these basic concepts. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here author consider two extra oppositely directed forces along the rod for the seek of calulation. This two forces being oppositely directed, there will be no net force for this and would not cause any rotation of the rod. Now the combination force of $f$ and $F_2$ gives the resultant ${F_2}^{'}$ which makes an angel $\theta_1$ with the rod. similarly the forces $f$ and $F_1$ gives the resultant ${F_1}^{'}$. Now we know that when a force acting through the point of ratation, does not cause any torque i.e. there will be no rotation. 
[image]

Now if the rod does not rotate for the two forces then the resultant of them ($F$) must be pass through $O$ and for this ${F_2}^{'}$ and ${F_1}^{'}$ should intersect at a point on the perpendicular line $OP$.

Comment: Thanks for your diagram. But I still don't 100% understand. I am not sure if I miss some of the concepts. If there is f acts along the rod, it will cause translational motion not rotation?

Comment: Yes, the force $f$ does not cause nither rotation nor translation. Because there present two force of same magnitude $f$ but oppsitly directed. Therefore they cancel each other. So there is no story of the $f$ forces for the net force is zero over the rod. see the fig. more closely..

Comment: Here we are talking about the motion of the whole rod. so we have the calculate the total force on the rod. Now since there is a force $f$ and another force $-f$ i.e. oppositly directed to the first force. Hence we can say there is no extra force over the rod since $f+(-f)=0$

Comment: Thanks. How about the diagram 10.1 (b)? also he said point P is above point O?

Comment: There author first takes two similar and opposite directed force $f$ and then taking one of them, draw the diagram 10.1(b). That's why I've drawn the complete fig.

Comment: Yes. But is there any difference? in his diagram, Point P is above Point O, but in yours, it is below.

Comment: There is no force component above the rod because all the forces acting downward direction or horizontal to the rod. So the point $P$ must be below the rod.

Comment: I don't know why author says "$P$ is above the rod". But whether the point situated above or below the rod, the ultimate result remain same.